# How to add stickers to my image in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Is there a library or component that you can add sticker images to an image that is taken from camera in react-native? (Like SnapChat)

Comment: did you found any answer ?

Comment: Yes, PhotoEditor SDK is available for Web and Native (Android, iOS). link photoeditorsdk.com

Comment: Try this https://github.com/JimmyDaddy/react-native-image-marker